# How to search node by exact text match using Xpath in webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

I need a little help regarding searching an exact text using xpath in webDriver.

Suppose i have the html as follows..

```
<html><body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button>abcd</button></td>
      <td><button>abc</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

Now i want to click button "abc"

I used xpath as `//button[contains(text(),'abc')]` but it is always performing on button "abcd" as it also contain the text "abc". In this regards I need a predicate or some other procedure which can search exact text instead of containing text.

I also tried with `//button[matches(text(),'abc')]`,  `//button[matches($string,'abc')]`, `//button[Text='abc')]`, `//button[.='abc')]` and many more but none of these worked out to identify "abc" button.

I do not know if there is any problem regarding my xpath version as I'm not aware of the version. But I'm using java 1.6 JDK.

Though my exact scenario is not the example shown but similar logic needs to be applied.

Hence any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it...what's wrong with an **equals** search? ...`//button[text()='abc']`....?

Comment: @Arrana looks like the wrong was `//button[Text='abc']` but the right one is `//button[Text()='abc']` (as you wrote)

Comment: Yes its absolutely right....it would be something like an Equal search...//button[text()='abc'] this xpath works properly...thanks a lot.

Comment: How to do case-insensitive exact match?

Answer (score 58):

I would use next xpath `//button[text()='abc']`. You have mentioned `text()` function but I'm not sure syntax was correct. Also you tried to use `contains()` -- it searches partial text and WebDriver gets first element found. I your case it is `<button>abcd</button>` button

Answer (score 20):

To find the element 'abcd' you can simply use:

```
//button[contains(text(),'abcd')]
```

To find 'abc' use the normalize-space() function which will clean up your text for comparison purposes.

```
//button[normalize-space(text())='abc']
```

Comment: normalize-space example worked for me on Selenium IDE for chrome

Answer (score 15):

For exact search:

```
button[text()='abc']
```

For pattern matching search:

```
button[starts-with(.,'abc')]
```

Comment: `button[starts-with(.,'abc')]` is not working.

Answer (score 13):

```
//button[.="abc"]
```

The dot before the equality operator will do the text comparison.  Another example is `/PROJECT[.="MyProject"]` from the [xPath Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try with ends-with instead of contains. If the buttons dont have unique attributes, you can add the parent hierarchy as well. Like //table/tr/td[1].

Comment: thanx for ur comment, tell me one thing, the html contains leading and trailing space for the text. like " abcd " and " abc ".if I use [contains(text(),'abc')] xpath then its performing on "abcd" button. but if i'm using [starts-with(text(),' abc') or [ends-with(text(),'abc '), its showing unable to find locator.the space i mentioned in xpath leading or trailing to the string is correct??And secondly the "td" number is not fixed in my case. the button may contain in any td in the table. infact in some other tr tag also as the button generation is dynamic. Hence I can't go by hierarchy.

Comment: Cannot tell without accessing the application but you can do it the round about way by getting text attribute value and do a string comparison using the language functions.

Comment: Element.getattribute("text")

Comment: thanx for the suggestion. It would be better if i had a predicate to match for an exact text. though it was a bit hectic anyway i made the library using string checking by Element.getText() method and now its working fine...

Comment: @souvik The `normalize-space()` function will clean up your text for comparison purposes.  Try `//button[normalize-space(text())='abc']`

Comment: It is commom to accept or upvote if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like below worked perfectly fine for me.

```
//button[(contains(.,'abc')) and not(contains(.,'abcd'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

For exact search:
.//button[./text()='abc']

Note: make you there is no space is available into

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`//td//text()` will select both buttons

`(//td//text())[1]` will select `<button>abcd</button>`

`(//td//text())[2]` will select `<button>abc</button>`