# Click only on Follow buttons at instagram

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create an instagram bot that follows all followers of a page.

I have this line of code

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
```

The problem is that it clicks also the buttons which i already have followed and they write "**Following** on them. Is there any way to click ONLY the Follow buttons and not anything that contains the word "Follow"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search node by exact text match using Xpath in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721111/how-to-search-node-by-exact-text-match-using-xpath-in-webdriver)

Comment: before clicking on button get text from button and check if it is `Following` or `Follow` You could also check if buttons `Following` and `Follow` don't have other different elements - ie. some class, attribute, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath allows for AND's and NOT's. See below:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow') and not(contains(.,'Following')) ]")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the xpath for this kind of situation by adding more conditions on it.
You can use any of the below xpath-

1. //button[contains(.,'Follow')][not(contains(.,'Following'))]
2. //button[contains(.,'Follow') and not(contains(.,'Following'))]